# How to use a JS Regular Expression to turn every last letter in a block of text to bold

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to highlight the last letter of each word in bold for someone who has reading difficulties. I have this function so far but the regular expression highlights the first letter. How do I put the span tag around the last letter?

```
function myFunction() {
    var str = document.getElementById("view_text").innerHTML; 
    var res = str.replace(/\b([a-z])([a-z]+)?\b/gim, "<span class='last-letter'>$1</span>$2");
    document.getElementById("view_text").innerHTML = res;
}
```

Comment: Why the _last_, why not the _first_ ? What are the word letters and non-word letters ? If its a word boundry and a letter, all you need is `\w\b`. Regex is fairly simple.

Comment: @sln nice, simple and compact regex :)

Comment: @sln You are absolutely correct, `\w\b` is just enough. Your comment should be an answer.

Comment: @Jez See comment of sln, you should use this regexp.

Comment: What is the full line of regex to turn the last letter bold (including single letter words)? The reason why it must be the last letter is because this person has a visual impairment blocking out the right side, requiring a letter in bold to signal the end of the word.

Answer (score -1):

Why use a regular expression?

You could use:

var n = str.length;

var $1 = str.substring(0, n-1);
var $2 = str.substring(n-1, n);

Comment: Because s?he needs to replace each last letter in the words and not just the last one in the sentence.

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried to use str.length route but couldn't work it out. I'm a beginner. I'm not sure what the $ does... is this jquery... what would be the full function?

Comment: Jez, I didn't read your question correct.The solution provided can be used for spliting a string in two parts: the string without the last letter and the last letter. You could put span tags around the last string and then glue the two strings together again. As HamZa mentions: this will only highlight the last letter of the sentence. When you want to highlight the last letter of each word you have to split up the sentence (string) in words first. This is possible but much more code then the solution with the regular expression. The $ has no meaning. $1 is just a arbitrary variable name.